# intersection of circumferences

Tags: calculus

I have two circumferences (K1 with centre O1 and K2 with centre O2) with radius 1 and square root of 2, respectively.
Intersections of circumferences are called A and B.
I must find a point C of K2 so that the midpoint of segment AC is on K1.
Morevoer, I have to set length of AC if the distance between centers are 2

Comment: The word "circumference" should be replaced by the word  " circle" ; square root of 2 is written '$ \ s q r t \{ 2 \} $' in latex

Comment: What have you done on this subject ? Where are you blocked ?

Answer (score 0):

A circle's radius always equals the square root of the number $$n$$ in the equation $$x² + y² = n$$

K1 has a radius of 1 therefore the circle has the equation $$x² + y² = √1 = 1$$

K2 has a radius of √2 therefore has the equation $$x² + y² = 2$$

You can draw this on a graph and find the points at which they intersect that way; the mathematical way is more complex.

Comment: Those equations are for circles both centered at the origin, which these are not.

Comment: You can still derive a correct radius from them, but I integrand your premise and you are correct.